# Tuning Netty on 32 Core / 10Gbit Hosts

Tags: performance, networking, netty

Netty Server streams to a Netty client (point to point, 1 to 1):

### Good

- case: Server and Client are both `12 cores`, `1Gbit NIC` => going at the steady rate of 300K 200 byte messages per second

### Not So Good

- case: Server and Client are both `32 cores`, `10Gbit NIC` => (same code) starting at 130K/s degrading down to hundreds per second within minutes

### Observations

- Netperf shows that the "bad" environment is actually quite excellent ( can stream 600MB/s steady for a half an hour ).
- It does not seem to be a client issue, since if I swap the client to a *known* good client (wrote it in C) that sets a max OS's `SO_RCVBUF` and does nothing but reads byte[]s and ignores them => the behavior is still the same.
- Performance degradation starts before a high write watermark ( 200MB, but tried others ) is reached
- Heap feels up quickly, and of course once reaches the max, GC kicks in locking the world, but that happens way after the "bad" symptoms surface. On a "good" environment heap stays steady somewhere at 1Gb, where it logically, given the configs, should be.
- One thing that I noticed: *most of the 32 cores are utilized* while Netty Server streams, which I tried to limit by setting all the Boss/NioWorker threads to `1` (although there is a single channel anyway, but just in case):

```scala
val bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
  new NioServerSocketChannelFactory (
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 ),
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 ), 1 ) )

// 1 thread max, memory limitation: 1GB by channel, 2GB global, 100ms of timeout for an inactive thread
val pipelineExecutor = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(
                1, 1 *1024 *1024 *1024, 2 *1024 *1024 *1024, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
  Executors.defaultThreadFactory() )

bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(
  new ChannelPipelineFactory {
    def getPipeline = {
      val pipeline = Channels.pipeline( serverHandlers.toArray : _* )
      pipeline.addFirst( "pipelineExecutor", new ExecutionHandler( pipelineExecutor ) )
      pipeline
    }
} )
```

But that does not limit the number of cores used => still most of the cores are utilized. I understand that Netty tries to round robin worker tasks, but have a suspicion that 32 cores "at once" may be just too much for the NIC to handle.

### Question(s)

1. Suggestions on the degrading performance?
2. How do I limit the number of cores used by Netty (without of course going the OIO route)?

*side notes: would've loved to discuss it on Netty's mailing list, but it is closed. tried Netty's IRC, but it is dead*

Comment: would like to see someone authoritative answer this one...:) The netty google group is not dead, even though it just shows the github updates for the past month. I see trustin etc posting to it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/netty

Comment: @tolitius what are the bootstrap options set for client/server pipelines?

Comment: Pinning the java process to few cores and optimise the tcp stack for 10G NEC will help a bit? http://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2009/ols2009-pages-169-184.pdf

Comment: Jestan, bootsrap: watermarks, tcpnodelay, keepalive, reuseaddress, backlog. also tried writeSpinCount (it is defaulted to to 16 in DefaultNioSocketChannelConfig), send/receive buffer. As to # of cores, I disabled some cores through BIOS, so Netty can't even see them => problem remains. However Netty still creates 20+ threads, I can't find a way to throttle it. As to 10G link => network is absolutely fine. I wrote my own test streamer on top of vanilla java.nio, and can stream 800K 200 byte messages a second. It is a Netty server beast that I can't yet handle.

Comment: Please specify `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` when you construct a `ChannelFactory`.  Using a fixed thread pool will guarantee a lockup.

Comment: Trustin, "newCachedThreadPool" is what I have started from. Then I went searching for ways to limit the number of threads. I did provide my own `threadFactory` to a "newCachedThreadPool", but that also did not seem to narrow down the number of threads.

Comment: I wonder what happened to this question? I have a similar web server that basically is a http request logger and I am facing the same problem, the performance of the netty server just tanks after heap reaches max and GC kicks in. Something seems broken, but have no clue what to start looking at?

Comment: "heap reaches max and GC kicks in" would most likely be your problem. the above was not solved, and a native Java NIO was used to "send".

Answer (score 2):

have you tried cpu/interrupt affinity? 
the idea is to send io/irq interrupts into 1 or 2 cores only and prevent context switch in other cores.
give it a good. try vmstat and monitor ctx and inverse context switched before and after. 
you may unpin the application from the interrupt handler core(s).